# my c# unity script(tank game) and transform.LookAt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankScopeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private float waitTime;
    public float startWaitTime;
    public Transform[] moveSpots;
    private int randomSpot;
    public Transform random;


    void Start()
    {
        random = moveSpots[Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length)];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[random].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[random].position) < 0.2f)
        {
            if (waitTime <= 0)
            {
                random = moveSpots[Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length)];
                waitTime = startWaitTime;
                transform.LookAt(random);



                
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

want to use transform.LookAt(randomSpot) but i cant...error with int to transform, help me please...
i tried to create public Transform random; and assign a value randomSpot, but, again error
Assets\Resources\Script2\TankScopeScript.cs(23,70): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'int'

Comment: Please provide more details. What error do you get (exact error message)? Where do you get that error? What have you tried so far to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get an element of an array using the `random` variable, but that is one of your points rather than an index. Instead of using `moveSpots[random].position` you should replace it with `random.position`.

So line 23 would become `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, random.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);` and line 25 would become `if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, random.position) < 0.2f)`.